# Using Spring autowired bean from other project in JUnit

Tags: spring, maven, junit, dependencies, autowired

I'm writing unit tests for my app consisting of several projects. I have project A for which I'm writing tests, and project B where I want to store some needed beans to be autowired in A test classes.
Prject A also needs B in the compilation scope.

If using dependency like that:

```
...
A/pom.xml
...
<dependency>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
<dependency>
```

spring is unable to autowire beans of B project. It's strange, because according to the Maven docs, compile scope also makes project content available at the stage phase.

In case I use the save dependency but with test scope, unit tests work, but app itself faild (pretty predictable).

In case when I use both dependencies, like:

```
...
A/pom.xml
...
<dependency>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
<dependency>

<dependency>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
<dependency>
```

mvn clean install fails since it's unable to resolve dependencies.

So what can I do? Is there any best practise of using other project beans in unit tests in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

The default maven scope (compile) should do it. Should give you access to the classes at compile/test time.

You  should look at:

- what packaging do you use for each project (jar/war)
- how are you autowiring beans from B to A, does the autowiring works at runtime,
- maybe there is a difference on how you create the Spring context at test time VS runtime
- could be that Spring auto-scan mechanism doesn't scan the B project packages (at least in tests)

Answer (score 0):

We usually do it like :
`<dependency>
      <artifactId>B</artifactId>
      <groupId>groupID</groupId>
      <version>version number</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>jar or war</type>
    </dependency>`